# return value is undefined in C

Tags: c

Not sure if I'm overthinking for this, but how would I return something undefined when the parameter is not in the range that needs to be?

I'm trying to do:

```
uint64_t function(uint64_t Value, uint64_t N) {
   uint64_t result = 0;

   if (N > 0){
     //do something;
     return result;
   }
   else{
     return result is undefined;
   }
}
```

How do I return N is undefined?

Comment: Well one option would be: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value

Comment: In your case, it depends on the range of possible values your function can return. If you know this range, then you can pick up a value outside of it as an undefined value.

Comment: One possibility is to do like the C library calls and set errno = ERANGE.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to return a status and use an OUT parameter like so:

```
bool function(uint64_t Value, uint64_t N, uint64_t *result) {

   if (N > 0){
     //do something;
     *result = 31337;
     return true;
   }
   else{
     return false;
   }
}
```

Then when you call this function you check that the function returns true before using the result.

Comment: I can't change it to boolean. It has to be a function of type uint64_t

Comment: @Tavo use `uint64_t function(..., bool *isUndefined)` prototype then.

Answer (score 3):

For integer types, you can't.

There are exactly 2<sup>64</sup> possible values of type `uint64_t`, and each one of them is a valid integer value.

In some cases, you can choose one value (perhaps `UINT64_MIN`) that you can treat as an error indication, and return that -- but that's not always practical.

Or you can have the function return a success or failure result, and communicate the `uint64_t` value back to the caller by some other means, probably by storing it via a pointer passed in by the caller.

Comment: if I do: ...else{return -1;} } 

N has to be greater than 0 else the function should return undefined.

Comment: @Tavo: If you do `return -1;` in a function returning `uint64_t`, the `-1` will be converted to `18446744073709551615`. There is no undefined value for `uint64_t` -- unless you define it yourself by convention.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to return a struct. This works better in C++ (look at Boost Optional) but here's a C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct optional_int {
    bool valid;
    int  value;
};

struct optional_int f(int x)
{
    struct optional_int result = {false, 0};
    if(x > 0 && x < 10) {
        result.valid = true;
        result.value = x * 1024;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    struct optional_int v;

    v = f(9);
    if(v.valid) {
        printf("Result is %d\n", v.value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```